# Changing sublime key bindings to move to the beginning and end of line

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2

I'm currently looking at [this useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14406139/1655567) published on SO about modifying Sublime Text key bindings. I would like to check whether it's possible to assign those arrow keys:

[image: arrow keys]

to move to the **beginning** and **end** of current line? Presently the keys don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this thread](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5830) has the answer you want:

```
{ "keys": ["end"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol"} }, {
keys": ["home"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol"} }
```